# How to go back to prev screeen after navigating from one stack to the other nested stack in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

I have code something similiar to this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen', {
              screen: "Details",
              initial: false,
              params: {
                initial: false,
              },
         )} //------------------------- navigating to different nested stack
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

After navigating from the HomeScreen to the DetailsScreen of the Settings screen, I can't go back to the screen I was on (HomeScreen). It returns me to the SettingsScreen.

If I use a custom back button with `navigation.goBack()`, it always returns me to the HomeScreen, even if I am on the SettingsScreen and navigate to the DetailsScreen and then press go back. It should navigate to the SettingsScreen instead of the HomeScreen.

How to correctly implement **goBack** functionality?

Should I add to each stack DetailsScreen? in my case seems not right as DetailsScreen should belong only to SettingsScreen.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to call navigation.getParent()?.goBack() to do this.

Comment: this not working at all